# Migrating from Java Page Flow to JSF

Tags: jsf, weblogic, portal, migrate, beehive

I am currently working on a project that uses WebLogic Portal and Apache Beehive Page Flow Controller.

The team would like to remove WebLogic Portal and the Page Flow Controllers with JSF. Currently we have not found a way to manage the workflow with JSF as with PFC.

With Spring MVC it would be easy because we only remove Beehive annotations using Spring MVC Annotations but we would like to go directly with JSF so later we can start using icefaces.

Any suggestions of where I can find information about what we want to do?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: JSf doesn't support flows yet. That feature will be available in [the upcoming JSF 2.2](http://jdevelopment.nl/jsf-22/)

Comment: That is correct. For the time being due to Weblogic Portal dependency, we are going to migrate to JSF 1.2, then when we remove wlp we will update to JSF 2.0.